# Cross build scala using gradle

Tags: scala, gradle

I've got a Scala project that is built with Gradle.  The Scala code is source compatible with scala 2.9 and 2.10 and I'd like to cross build it to both major Scala versions.  Does Gradle support this?

For example, my gradle project will have a single module:

```
    build.gradle
    src/main/scala/foo.scala
```

and I'd like the resulting published jars to be:

```
    org-foo_2.9-0.1.jar (with dependency on scala-library 2.9)
    org-foo_2.10-0.1.jar (with dependency on scala-library 2.10)
```

Comment: issue tracker ticket about it: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3530

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle's Scala plugin doesn't currently support cross-building. It's possible to implement it yourself, though. In my [Polyglot Gradle](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4449-polyglot-gradle-java-groovy-scala-and-beyond) talk, I presented a proof-of-concept.

Comment: This sounds interesting (+1), but all the content seems to hidden behind some login screen (-1) ... It would be awesome if you could post some actual content as part of your answer.

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to post the whole POC here. If you do need this feature today, I recommend that you watch the video (starting at 48:30) and develop your own solution based on the ideas presented there. This will certainly take some effort (the POC isn't complete).

Comment: Thanks Peter,  I'll use something along these lines.  Looking forward to full gradle support in the future.

Comment: Peter I was wondering if there was any update on cross compile support for gradle?

Answer (score 6):

I am searching for a good example of this. The [Gradle manual](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) doesn't mention how to specify Scala version but looking at [the source code for the Scala plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/scala/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/ScalaRuntime.java#L93) it seems to infer it from the Scala library jar that you specify.

The best example I could find is the [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org) build system. It [specifies the Scala version](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/gradle.properties#L18) and then uses some [additional logic](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/build.gradle#L215) to resolve the correct version of the Scala libraries. It also uses some logic to [attach the correct label](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/build.gradle#L140) to the jars its builds to correspond to the correct Scala version.

This feels like a lot of work and something that the build system should do for you [like in SBT](http://rosslawley.co.uk/posts/how-to-handle-multiple-scala-versions/).